# how to launch a fragment from an activity other than the main parent activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

i have a Main Activity( activity A ) which has a frame layout that shows 3 fragments ie fragment A,fragment B and fragment C. i have another activity which has a button. When i click that button i want it to open fragment B. how do i open a fragment that belongs to another activity. i have tried the following code

```
 android.app.Fragment fragment = new ImageGridFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

but this seems to work only if you change fragments from the main parent fragment. how can i overcome this and show another fragment belonging top another activity?

Comment: I think you have to pass some identify data to Activity A so base on respective fragment will be added to frame layout.

Comment: Do you want to open fragment B in your MainActivity or in your second activity?

Comment: @rickyalbert in the mainActivity

Comment: And you want to show immediately that fragment or when the user changes activity?

Comment: @rickyalbert immediately

Comment: I wrote the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass to your MainActivity some data to let it know that it has to open FragmentB. For example use this in your secondActivity

```
Intent openFragmentBIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
openFragmentBIntent.putExtra(OPEN_FRAGMENT_B, SOME_VALUE);
startActivity(openFragmentBIntent);
```

and in your MainActivity `onCreate`:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra(OPEN_FRAGMENT_B)
{
    Fragment fragment = new ImageGridFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: thank you @rickyalbert it worked.. :) but im assuming other than this these no other way around this problem?

Comment: I think this is the faster and simplest way to achieve this. In Android programming if you have to communicate something to an Activity you have to use the Intent that calls it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to open your activity A and pass a parameter (for example via extras) so that you are able to launch / open the correct fragment.

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().hasExtra("something")) {

    }
}
```